# How can I know which element has a class?

Tags: jquery, class, html

My page has six `div` elements.

Using jQuery and Z-Index, clicking on a button increases the width of one `div` to cover all the others. In the process, it also assumes the class: `active` (z-index:900).

When I click another button, the `div` with the class `active` should return to its original size and position. The original values are saved into variables, but how can I know the name of the element with the `active` class?

Comment: Hiya, look for api `hasClass` and you can use `.each` to loop through your divs, hope this helps bruv! have a good one! cheerios!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the fundamental features of the [`jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) aka `$()`.

Doing this:

```
var elements = $(".myclass");
```

will give you all of the elements that are using CSS class `myclass`.  From there you can do this:

```
elements.css({
    left: orig_left,
    top: orig_top,
    width: orig_width,
    height: orig_height
});
```

The style changes will apply to all of the elements at once.

However if you wish to restore an element to its defaults (ie what was in the original html), you can do this:

```
elements.css({
    left: null,
    top: null,
    width: null,
    height: null
});
```

or even:

```
elements.attr("style","");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.active')[0].id`
 Will get you ID of first element having class of 'active'

Comment: `$('.active')[0].id`, javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements with the class: `$('.youClass')`.